# Trying to fire an action in my controller when a selection in a drop down menu is made but getting a no route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a web interface to accompany a mobile app I'm building. I have a drop down select menu that lists a bunch locations.

On selection of a location I want to make a call to a method in my controller and grab some destinations within the location that was selected (each location has several destinations).

I then would like to render my show template with these results allowing the user to select a destination and make a booking.

This is what I have so far:

**My view with a list of resorts:**

```
<%= form_tag :url => { :action => :show } do %>
<%= select_tag :resort , options_for_select(@resorts), :prompt => 'Select Resort', :onchange => 'submit()' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
          @resorts = ["A","B", "C", "D", "E"]
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
  end

  def show
    @activities = Parse::Query.new("Activity").tap do |a|
      a.eq("resort", params[:resort])
    end.get
  end

end
```

Just slightly confused. Using form_for makes more sense to me with CRUD in mind and also because the form is object based.

I'd like to just take the selected resorted and pass it into a method in my controller that goes into a database and grabs a bunch of destinations. I then want to list these destinations on my show page where a user can click and be taken to another page where they can make a booking at that destination.

My above code doesn't work. I have resources :home in my routes file.

However when I try to load my page with the form I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"home"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

How do I pull this off?

I went on my lynda account and pulled up a rails essential tutorial which I'll have to use to refresh my memory some time tomorrow but the tutor doesn't cover use of select_tag.

Would appreciate some help here

Thanks for your time

Comment: *Using form_for makes more sense to me* -- why are you using `form_tag` instead of `form_for` then?

Answer (score 1):

So a few thoughts. Not sure why you are using `form_tag` and also not sure why you aren't using Rails idiomatic conventions.

Declare a resource in your `routes` for `@resorts`, like so:

```
resources :resorts
```

Then just use Rails `form_for` helper like:

```
<%= form_for @resorts, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :resort, (insert your other options) %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

I have not tested the above code, so play around with it, but that should work.

However, let me save you some headache. Checkout [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

For your models, you would want to setup an association between your locations and destinations.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resort # or whatever the relation is
  has_many :destinations   
end

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location # This assumes there is just a one-to-many relationship between Location and Destination
end
```

Make sure you have a `LocationsController` with all the actions.

In this case, your SimpleForm form would look something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @locations do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

That approach will make your life much easier. Take a look at the collections methods in Simple Form. Rails can make your life difficult with the built in form helpers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The thing is this rails app is not model based. I'm not using active record. My data is coming from parse.com

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, add

```
get '/choose_resort' => 'home#show' #you can name the get whatever
```

Then in your form...

```
<%= form_tag choose_resort_path do %>
```

That being said... you should have your query at a separate endpoint, and redirect to the show page. That should get you moving, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

The `show` action needs an `id` of the object you are showing.  Change your controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @resorts = [["A",1], ["B",2],  ["C",3], ["D",4], ["E",5] ]
  end
```

And your view

```
<%= select_tag :id , options_for_select(@resorts), :prompt => 'Select Resort', :onchange => 'submit()' %>
```

That gives your `show` action the proper resort id.  You'll have to adjust that action to find the right activities relevant to the resort.